# Copy GridView data to table in database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

[image: this is gridiview1]

I have data in a GridView and I need to copy it to a table in a database.

Let's say my first GridView is GridView1; GridView1's database source is subjects_enrolled. After I'm done using GridView1 it's data needs to clear and in addition, clear the data in the source table.

Note: The primary purpose of GridView1 is for displaying data for printing a page, but I want to save or transfer all data in GridView1 to a database table before losing the GridView1 data.

Here is my code so far:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("mcbdatabseConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Subject_ID, Subject, Units FROM mcbdatabse.subject_enrolled")
                Using sda As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt
                        GridView1.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
    txtDate.Text = Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
End Sub
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you just post a plain text containing just your question please refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also please provide us what you've done so far

Comment: @ShadowFiend Okay, I edited my pst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you doing some unnormal activity about databases you can be sure that you are in a bad plan. So in your case i can not understand why you want to do this.
You have better ways to do this, you can put all data in one table and add a column named 'enrolld' to filter data as you want and on user click you can delete or enrol the record.
But if you want to continue this way, you we have some events in gridview that can help:

> RowDeleting, RowUpdating

If a row affected the related event fires and you can get the id of the record:

```
protected sub GridView1_RowDeleting(byval sender as object, byval e as GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    {
        dim a as object = e.Keys["Id"]
    'or
        dim a as object = e.Keys[0]
    }
```

To access the id of your record and do what you want with this.

Comment: All the data in that table is enrolled subjects. I want to transfer data from that table because I want to use it to show all the subjects that was enrolled by a specific student. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Pls help me if you understand.

Comment: Did you test what i suggested?

Comment: Grab your table from server explorer to you aspx file in visual studio. There will automatically create a grid view and a sqldataSource set to it. In your grid view enable row delete and row update. so you have delete and update button in each row. Then in grid view events find RowDeleting, double click that and test my answer in top..

Comment: Thank you for helping but, the purpose of the table is just to display data and delete it afterwards. It is a temporary table for showing data so I want to  transfer these data to another table for retrieval.